# How do I express this expression using partial fractions?

Tags: partial-fractions

The expression I'm trying to express using partial fractions is: $\frac{64x}{(2x-1)^2(2x+1)^2}$

What I've tried so far:

$\frac{64x}{(2x-1)^2(2x+1)^2}=\frac{A}{(2x-1)^2}+\frac{B}{2x-1}+\frac{C}{(2x+1)^2}+\frac{D}{2x+1}$ where $A,B,C,D$ are constants

Multiplying each term by $(2x-1)^2(2x+1)^2$ gives
$64x=A(2x+1)^2+B(2x-1)(2x+1)^2+C(2x-1)^2+D(2x+1)(2x-1)^2$

Now:
$x=-\frac{1}{2} \implies -32=4C \implies C=-8$
$x=\frac{1}{2} \implies 32=4A \implies A=8$
$x=0 \implies 0=A-B+C+D \implies B=D$
$x=1 \implies 64=9A+9B+C+3D \implies 0=3B+D$

Solving the two simultaneous equations yields $B=D=0$

Hence:
$\frac{64x}{(2x-1)^2(2x+1)^2}=\frac{8}{(2x-1)^2}-\frac{8}{(2x+1)^2}$

But we know this is wrong since, checking with $x=1$ gives:

$\frac{64}{9}=\frac{1}{9}$ which is obviously wrong.

So my questions are:
(1) What method(s) can we use to express this in partial fractions?
(2) What went wrong above?

Comment: The checking "with $x=1$" has a computational mistake.  Indeed $8 - \frac{8}{9} = \frac{64}{9}$.  Checking "with $x=0$" is easier, if less reassuring.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you get $\frac19$ when you checked for $x=1$.  Notice that

$$\frac8{(2(1)-1)^2}=\frac8{(2-1)^2}=\frac81=8$$

$$\frac8{(2(1)+1)^2}=\frac8{(2+1)^2}=\frac89$$

Thus,

$$\frac8{(2(1)-1)^2}-\frac8{(2(1)+1)^2}=8-\frac89=\frac{64}9$$

Similarly,

$$\frac{64(1)}{(2(1)-1)^2(2(1)+1)^2}=\frac{64}{1^23^2}=\frac{64}9$$

Just as suspected.

As far as I can tell, your partial fractions are done correctly.

Comment: Ah thank you so much. I'm such a numpty :p

Comment: @thebuddha Of course!  We all make silly mistakes after doing all the hard work, don't we?  :-/